# In a Lightning Web Component (LWC), is there a way for expressions to reference the data in the record of a lightning-record-view-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordviewform

lightning-record-view-form is given a object type and a recordId had retrieves data for that type for the record with the Id.  Then tags like lightning-output-field can reference field values.  What I'd like to do is reference field values from the record in various expressions.  Anyone know if there's a way to do that?  Example of what I'm trying to do below....

```
<lightning-record-view-form record-id= {recordId} object-api-name="Foo__c">
  <lightning-output-field field-name="Fee__c"></lightning-output-field>
  <template if:true={*some expression that Foo__c.Fum__c has a value*}>
    <lightning-output-field field-name="Fum__c"></lightning-output-field>
  </template>
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

My proposition is do to something like that:

**About solution**

You cannot have a direct expression in `if:true` like `if:true={something=someValue}` it needs to be in `.js` file. It forces you to create a getter (`get`) or just use some component property/variable.
You also need to get record data that can be quite easily retrieved via `uiRecordApi` without apex.

**Code**

```js
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import FUM from '@salesforce/schema/Foo__c.Fum__c';

const FIELDS = [FUM];

export default class Example extends LightningElement {

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS)
foo;

get isFumEqualSomeValue() {
    return getFieldValue(this.foo.data, FUM) === 'some value';
}
```

```html
<lightning-record-view-form record-id= {recordId} object-api-name="Foo__c">
  <lightning-output-field field-name="Fee__c"></lightning-output-field>
  <template if:true={isFumEqualSomeValue}>
    <lightning-output-field field-name="Fum__c"></lightning-output-field>
  </template>
  ...
```

Resources:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was going to say.